# How to search active cell's value on Google after adding filter

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search active cell's value of top 5 cells in a column. It will work smoothly if there is no filter added with offset(1,0) method. But when I am adding filter the offset method doesn't work on visible cells. It goes below the active cell(non visible cell).

How can I search active cell value 1 by 1 i.e. top 5 while having a filter ?

Below is the code for without filter:

```
  Sub searchActiveCellPr()
    Dim query As String
    Dim search_string As String
    Dim iedgepath As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 5
    query = ActiveCell.Text
    Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe -url http:google.com/search?q=" & search_string)

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 'This one also not working
    
       Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Loop over the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`?

Comment: I am sorry I didnt get you. Are you asking did I use  .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)? Yes I tried this one also but it didnt work. You can check on your side also. It will throw an error

Comment: It would be helpful to show *how* you tried using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

Comment: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

I am trying this, But it is selecting every cell

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73530015/edit)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad What part I should edit?

Comment: The part where you show us _how_ you tried using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` maybe?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Done. I waiting for someone to answer this question.

Comment: You select cells but don't seem to do anything with them after you have selected them, [This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: You can use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` on a multi-cell range (perhaps the entire column here?) and then loop through its result.

Comment: @BigBen Can you please write a code to show your solution?